# Resource Dictionaries in WinRT class libraries (DLLs)

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, resourcedictionary

Does anyone know whether WinRT really supports creating class libraries (DLLs) using C# (or VB I suppose) with embedded XAML Resource Dictionaries and then add a reference to those DLLs in another project and merge in that dictionary or even load the dictionary from "resources" into an in-memory string?

It seems that this should fundamentally be supported, but I can't seem to get it to work, because when I add a reference to that DLL, I always get an error that there is a missing payload. Now I know that the XAML file doesn't actually get compiled into the DLL and instead is just deployed as part of the appx. And Visual Studio apparently has trouble with that, but I can manually copy the file into a different location to at least make that problem go away. (This was considered a known issue before release as far as I know, but I can't seem to get it to work out of the box in the release version either). Furthermore, even if I do manage to add the reference, I still don't seem to have access to the resource dictionary. I tried in various ways, such as merging it into other resources (using ms-appx syntax). I also tried to load the dictionary from the file into a string just to see if I could gain access. No dice it seems.

Oh, and if I then wanted to give such a DLL to someone else, how exactly would I deploy that? Is there a recommended approach?

Answer (score 4):

[Tim's article](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/03/07/creating-custom-controls-for-metro-style-apps.aspx) is the best guidance on creating custom controls and it should also work for resource dictionaries. Basically you have an option of building a NuGet package (these don't really have to be shared publicly - you can share/add private NuGet packages easily) or building an extension that installs into Visual Studio and becomes available to all apps.

You can also share the packages manually of course. Assuming your application references your MyLibrary.dll that is located in

```
MySolution/MyApplication/Dependencies/MyLibrary.dll
```

you also need to put the [.pri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj552947.aspx) file in the same folder like this:

```
MySolution/MyApplication/Dependencies/MyLibrary.pri
```

then you put the resources in a subfolder named like the library in the same subfolder hierarchy as they are in the library project, e.g.

```
MySolution/MyApplication/Dependencies/MyLibrary/Themes/Generic.xaml
MySolution/MyApplication/Dependencies/MyLibrary/Resources/Brushes.xaml
MySolution/MyApplication/Dependencies/MyLibrary/Resources/TextBlockStyles.xaml
MySolution/MyApplication/Dependencies/MyLibrary/Resources/ButtonStyles.xaml
...
```

Once you do that - Visual Studio will automatically pick these files up and put them in the appx package when it builds the app.